# Does there exist analytic functions satisfying the following property?

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, analytic-functions

Which one of the following two statements is/are true?

$(\text a)$ There exists an analytic function $f\colon\Bbb C \longrightarrow \Bbb C$ such that $f(z) = z$ for all $z$ with $|z|=1$ and $f(z) = z^2$ for all $z$ with $|z|=2.$

$(\text b)$ There exists an analytic function $f\colon\Bbb C \longrightarrow \Bbb C$ such that $f(0) = 1,f(4i) = i$ and for all $z_j$ with $1 < |z_j| < 3,$ $j = 1,2,$ we have $$|f(z_1) - f(z_2)| \leq |z_1 - z_2|^{\pi/3}.$$

How do I proceed to find the correct option. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) It follows from that identity theorem that if $\lvert z\rvert=1\implies f(z)=z$, then $f(z)=z$ everywhere. Therefore, the answer is negative.

b) If $1<|z|<3$, then$$f'(z)=\lim_{w\to z}\frac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z}=0,$$since$$\left|\frac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z}\right|\leqslant|w-z|^{\pi/3-1}$$and $\frac\pi3-1>0$. So, $f$ is constant on the annulus $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid1<|z|<3\}$. Therefore, again by the identity theorem, it is constant, and therefore we can't have both $f(0)=1$ and $f(4i)=i$.

Comment: Oops...Looks pretty straightforward and easy. I have done $(\text a)$ on my own actually. But the complicated expression given in option $(\text b)$ misguided me completely. Good answer! +1.

Comment: In question (b) how does $f(0) = 1\ $?

Comment: @Anacardium My answer is wrong. I will edit it in a few minutes.

Comment: What I can see is that if $|f(z_1) - f(z_2)| \leq |z_1 - z_2|^{\frac {\pi} {3}},$ for all $z_j,$ $j = 1,2$ with $1 \lt |z_j| \lt 3$ then we have $f'(z) = 0$ on the annulus $1 \lt |z| \lt 3.$ But then by the identity theorem it follows that $f'(z) = 0$ for all $z \in \Bbb C.$ That means $f$ has to be a constant function. Which can't be true by the given condition.

Comment: @Anacardium Well, that's my answer too.

Comment: I wonder how can such a erroneous answer be accepted by the OP? Even nobody has pointed out the error for almost 5 years. How ridiculous it is!

Comment: My knowledge of complex analysis is rudimentary, so please regard the comment in that light.  Is $f[re^{(i\theta)}] = r^r e^{(ir\theta)}$ an analytic function?

Comment: @Anacardium And it seems that nobody read it between the moment it got accepted and the moment you read it.

Comment: For what its worth: it just hit me:
Under the assumption that Arg$(z) ~\in ~\(-\pi, \pi]$
and under the convention that (for example) $z^{r} : 0 < r < 1$ will have a
negative Argument if and only if Arg$(z)$ is negative, then 
$f[re^{(i\theta)}] = r^r e^{(ir\theta)}$ will not be continuous at
$re^{(i\pi)} : 0 < r < 1.$ Interesting. Therefore, since my idea results in a function discontinuous on a portion of the negative real axis, it can't be an analytic function.